# How to use "select" with Beautiful Soup 4.7.1?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I used this code with beautifulsoup 4.6. Since version 4.7.1 this code shows me an error.

Can someone help me how to use "select" in the new version?

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= 'http://www.nordhessen-wetter.de'
u = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(u, 'html.parser')

lufttemperatur = soup.select('td:nth-of-type(10)')[0].text
```

This is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 9, in
>   
>       lufttemperatur = soup.select('td:nth-of-type(10)')[0].text IndexError: list index out of range

[live version of this code on repl.it](https://repl.it/@Marius82/YellowAmusedLint-1)

Comment: You need to show what the error is, in order for someone to help you with it. Please include the full traceback.

Comment: OK, I added the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your variable name I assume you are looking to extract the "Lufttemperatur in C" / "Aktuell" value.

If you look at your error you can see that the array index (10) is out of range - this might be because a change in how BeautifulSoup handles [CSS selectors in version 4.7](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) or it might be due to a change in the page.

Anyhow you can get the value you are looking for by changing to code a little bit. Instead of looking for the 10th TD, look for the TDs under the 4th TR and you'll get an array with the TDs for the Lufttemperatur row:

```
lufttemperatur = soup.select("tr:nth-of-type(4) > td") # array of TDs
```

or

```
lufttemperatur = soup.select("tr:nth-of-type(4) > td")[1] # Aktuell value for Lufttemp.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lufttemperatur = soup.select('td:nth-of-type(10)')[0]
```

I think that returns an empty list.

`'td:nth-of-type(10)'` I think means 'Selects every  element that is the tenth  element of its parent'.
Now, the parent of the td is tr. So, there are only 4 td in a tr.

`soup.select('td')[0]` gives you what you want?